# Pineapple houseplant growing issues

Tags: houseplants, pineapple

[image: pineapple plant Crown too heavy for its stem]

my pineapple houseplant has had a stressful summer whilst I was away. The plant wasn’t watered for about a month & some small leaves under the crown have dried out. After this stress the plant has started growing large long leafs on the top of the crown. Now the weight of the crown is too big for the stem. I found the plant bend over in the morning and resorted to tying wooden sticks to it to help it stand upright. I am wondering what is the best course of action to help my plant? It would be such a shame for it to die.